# How to find the integration of c$(\kappa$, d, $\alpha$)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Does one calculate the following integral:
\begin{equation}
     c(\kappa, d, \alpha) = \left(\frac{2\pi^{\frac{d-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{d-1}{2}\right)}\int_{0}^1\left( e^{\frac{\kappa}{\alpha}y^{\alpha}} +e^{-\frac{\kappa}{\alpha}y^{\alpha} }\right)(1-y^2)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}d\text{y}\right)^{-1}.
\end{equation}
where $d,\kappa >0$ and $\alpha \in (0,2]$

Thanks in advance:

Comment: Have you considered extending the interval of integration to $(-1,1)$ and using Gauss-Jacobi integration with $\alpha=\beta=(d-3)/2$? Is $d$ an integer or an arbitrary real number?

Comment: It seems the integral diverges.  I suppose if $\int_0^1 = +\infty$ then we can say $(\;)^{-1} = 0$.

Comment: @GEdgar. Not so sure in my humble opinion

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the integral as $$I_\alpha=\frac{4 \pi ^{\frac{d-1}{2}} }{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{d-1}{2}\right)}\int_0^1\left(1-y^2\right)^{\frac{d-3}{2}} \cosh
   \left(\frac{\kappa  }{\alpha }y^{\alpha }\right)$$  it seems that there are solutions in terms of  standard and regularized hypergeometric functions (they are really nasty if $d$ is not an integer).

If $d>1$, we have for example
$$I_1=2 \pi ^{\frac d2} \, _0\tilde{F}_1\left(;\frac{d}{2};\frac{\kappa ^2}{4}\right)$$
$$I_2=2^{\frac{4-d}{2}} \pi ^{\frac{d+2}{2}} \,
   _2\tilde{F}_3\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{1}{2},\frac{d+2}{4},\frac{d}{4};
   \frac{\kappa ^2}{16}\right)$$
$$I_3=\frac{2 \pi ^{\frac d2}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)} \,
   _2F_3\left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{5}{6};\frac{d+2}{6},\frac{d+4}{6}
   ,\frac{d}{6};\frac{\kappa ^2}{36}\right)$$

It is interesting to notice is how simplify $I_1$ for different values of $d$ (for $d=0,1,\cdots,5$)
$$\left\{\kappa  I_1(\kappa )\,,\,2 \cosh (\kappa )\,,\,2 \pi  I_0(\kappa )\,,\,\frac{4 \pi  \sinh
   (\kappa )}{\kappa }\,,\,\frac{4 \pi ^2 I_1(\kappa )}{\kappa }\,,\,\frac{8 \pi ^2 (\kappa 
   \cosh (\kappa )-\sinh (\kappa ))}{\kappa ^3}\right\}$$

Comment: It is great, thank you so much

Comment: Could you please show reference for this integral. I have to show reference in my project, @Claude Leibovici